# Can save and access data from Jotai atom inside getServerSideProps in next.js

Tags: next.js, jotai

I am using Jotai state management in my Next.js project.
I wonder if its possible to access data from Jotai Atom, and if it already has the data, I can skip re-fetching it from the API.

Something like this :

```
import { preferencesAtom, fetchPreferences } from '../store';
import { useAtom } from 'jotai';


export async function getServerSideProps(context)
{
    const [preferences, setPreferences] = useAtom(preferencesAtom);

    if(preferences != null)
    {
        const prefnces = await fetchPreferences(); // this will fetch preferences from API
        setPreferences(prefnces);
    }

    return {
        props: {
            preferences : preferences
        },
    };
}
```

Comment: You can't use `useAtom` inside `getServerSideProps`. `useAtom` is a custom React hook and can only be used in React components or other hooks. See the official Next.js Jotai example for how to use Jotai with SSR: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jotai.